# Pandas writes NaNs then chain assignment from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one pandas dataframe called `print_df` which collects values from a numpy record array `tv`. I am getting some very strange behavior when I try and do chain assignment between `print_df` and `tv.`

So I convert the record array into a pandas Dataframe called `tv.` Then I make sure that the columns of both dataframes are equivalent.

```
      for idx in range(number_of_runs):
        tv = pd.DataFrame(self.res_array['run'][idx], dtype='float64')
        tv.columns = ['year',
                        'f1',
                        'f2',
                        'f3',
                        'm1',
                        'm2',
                        'm3']

        print_df.ix[(idx * self.duration):(idx * self.duration +
                                          self.duration - 1), 0] = idx
        print_df.ix[(idx * self.duration):(idx * self.duration +
                                         self.duration - 1), 1:] = tv
```

Here is some sample data.

```
         year    f1   f2    f3    m1    m2     m3 
    0    0.0  14.0  3.0  19.0  37.0  28.0  239.0   
    1    1.0  13.0  6.0  20.0  38.0  25.0  238.0        
    2    2.0  12.0  8.0  20.0  40.0  23.0  239.0       
    3    3.0  13.0  9.0  21.0  40.0  22.0  238.0      
    4    4.0  16.0  9.0  21.0  38.0  22.0  239.0
```

The assignment works for the first iteration smoothly, but all subsequent iterations result in NaNs in the `print_df` dataframe. The sizes of the two dataframes are equivalent, so no problem there. I also tried this using index based selection `.iloc`, but that did not make a difference.

I also thought that the column names in `tv` could be causing the error, because one column was called `index.` That is why I make sure to explicitly name all of the columns.

There are certainly more pythonic ways to write this code, but I first want to get the chain assignment working before cleaning up the code.

Comment: Can you share with us a sample data of what is in `print_df`. Also, as a rough guess, can you ensure the data-type of the columns are the same if there any comparisons based assignments being done?

Comment: thanks @SreejithMenon . I added some sample data. They are all floats. I checked and all of the data types in both dataframes are float64. I was not doing any comparisons, this was a pure assignment. I am basically creating a large dataframe that collects data for export to csv.